# jQuery sortable groups and subgroups

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a `div` in which I want all the `h2`, `p` and `div` elements to be sortable. I also want to have sub-sortable groups in there and I want the elements from the main and the elements from the sub groups to be sortable with each other. So an element from the main group should be allowed to put into a sub group and back.

I've set up a jsFiddle in hope that I can display what I want. The idea is that the light grey elements should be able to be put into the group with the dark grays and the other way around.

http://jsfiddle.net/LpmfY/1/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sort_these').sortable();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class='sort_these'>
     <h2>...</h2>

    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class='sort_these'>
         <h2>...</h2>

        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably start with the [connectWith option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith), something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LpmfY/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sort_these').sortable({
        connectWith: '.sort_these'
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work but I'm getting into trouble when it wants to sort a parent into a child. Any way around that? I update the jsfiddle with to show when it's trying to sort inside itself: http://jsfiddle.net/LpmfY/4/

Answer (score 2):

You should check connectWith: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists